# Multiplying inputs with JQuery

Tags: jquery, math, input

I'm trying to multiply values of inputs using JQuery.

```
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="qtd[1]" size="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price[1]" size="10" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="total[1]" size="10" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="qtd[2]" size="2" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="price[2]" size="10" /></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="total[2]" size="10" /></td>
    </tr>
<input type="hidden" value="2" name="qtd_itens" />
```

Basically i'm trying to show the total[i] as soon as the user fills qtd[i] and price[i]..

```
$(':input').bind('keypress keydown keyup change',function(){
    for ($i = 0; $i < $(':input[name="qtd_itens"]').val(); $i++)

    var acho = parseFloat($(':input[name="qtd[' + $i + ' ]"]').val(),10),
    alto = parseFloat($(':input[name="price[' + $i + ']"]').val(),10);

    var v = '';
    if (!isNaN(acho) && !isNaN(alto)){
        v = (acho * alto);
    }
    $(':input[name="total[' + $i + ']"]').val(v.toString());
}
});
```

Any help?

code: http://jsfiddle.net/gilbertogm85/XSAk5/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code, missing `{` for the `for` statement. Also note that `parseFloat` function only accepts 1 argument, it seems you want to use the `parseInt` function which accepts radix as the second argument.

Instead of using the `for` loop which is not necessary you can select the closest `tr` and then set the value:

```
$('input').on('keyup change', function (e) {
    var $i = $(this).closest('tr').find('input'),
        acho = parseFloat($i.eq(0).val()),
        alto = parseFloat($i.eq(1).val()),
        val = (acho * alto);

    if ( !isNaN(val) ) {
        $i.eq(2).val(val);
    }
});
```

Comment: worked even better.. but same thing.. is ignoring the numbers after comma.. how could i do to dont ignore those numbers?

Comment: @GilbertoGonçalvesMachado You can replace the commas with empty strings using JavaScript `replace` method. After calculation you can format the result using regex. There are many related questions on the SO.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/XSAk5/7/):

```
$(function(){
    $('input[name^="price"]').on('keyup change',function(){
        var prc = $(this),
            qty = prc.closest('tr').find('input[name^="qtd"]'),
            tot = prc.closest('tr').find('input[name^="total"]');
        if(check(prc.val()) && check(qty.val())) {
            var p = parseFloat((prc.val()).replace(',','')),
                q = parseFloat((qty.val()).replace(',', '')),
                total = p * q;
            $(tot.val(total.toFixed(2)));
        }
    });

    function check($val) { return $val.match("^[0-9,\.]+$"); }
});
```

Comment: worked fine.. i have only another question.. we use prices like 1.230,00  but if i put that as a price it gives me a NaN result.. how could i fix that? also.. i changed that line     var total = prc.val() * parseFloat(qty.val(),2);

Comment: that didnt work... i tried quantity 3 and price 3.120,00 should give me a total 9.360,00 and its giving me 9.36 ... u know whats wrong?

Comment: @GilbertoGonçalvesMachado, Make sure the value is `9,360.00` not `9.360,00` I assumed this format.

Comment: @GilbertoGonçalvesMachado, Oh! I thought `1,000.00` do you need updated one or got the other one as required ?

Comment: @GilbertoGonçalvesMachado, updated the [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/XSAk5/8/) but not a good one `IMO`.

Comment: no.. and also.. if i put quantity 3 and price 3,00 its giving me 900.00 as result... basically prices in brazil are formated as xx.xxx,xx so if i multiply 3 x 3.120,20 it should give me a total of 9,360,60...